# 3-D interpolation using LinearNDInterpolator (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, multidimensional-array, scipy, interpolation

I want to interpolate some 3-d data using the scipy LinearNDInterpolator function (Python 2.7).  I can't quite figure out how to use it, though: below is my attempt.  I'm getting the error ValueError: different number of values and points.  This leads me to believe that the shape of "coords" is not appropriate for these data, but it looks in the documentation like the shape is okay.

Note that in the data I really want to use (instead of this example) the spacing of my grid is irregular, so something like RegularGridInterpolator will not do the trick.

Thanks very much for your help!

```
def f(x,y,z):
    return 2 * x**3 + 3 * y**2 - z

x = np.linspace(1,2,2)
y = np.linspace(1,2,2)
z = np.linspace(1,2,2)


data = f(*np.meshgrid(x, y, z, indexing='ij', sparse=True))

coords = np.zeros((len(x),len(y),len(z),3))
coords[...,0] = x.reshape((len(x),1,1))
coords[...,1] = y.reshape((1,len(y),1))
coords[...,2] = z.reshape((1,1,len(z)))
coords = coords.reshape(data.size,3)

my_interpolating_function = LinearNDInterpolator(coords,data)


pts = np.array([[2.1, 6.2, 8.3], [3.3, 5.2, 7.1]])
print(my_interpolating_function(pts))
```

Comment: your inputs (`coords` and `data`) have shapes (2,2,2) and (8,3). Is that correct? This doesn't look right to me. In the docs, the first dim of each input (`npoints`) must be the same! Since your function returns a single value from three parameters, coords should be shaped (N, 3) and data should be (N, 1).